# class、interfaceまたはenumがありません、と出てしまいます。どこが悪いでしょうか？教えてください。

Tags: java

```
new class Kama
{
    static String name = "ああああ様";
    static int yen;             
    static int seki;                

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws java.io.IOExcepion
    {
        int     yes = System.in.read();

        if( yes = 1){
            System.out.println("ありがとう!!" + name);
        }else{
            System.out.ptintln("キャンセルされました。" +name);
        }
        System.out.println("yes is" + yes );
    }
}
```

Comment: new class Kama< ここの new を public に して見ましょ!

Comment: そして、`if(yes = 1)`を`if(yes==1)`にしなければならないと考えています。

Comment: スペルミスがありますね。。。`java.io.IOExcepion`, `System.out.ptintln`

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode まぁ、そこは文字コードになるので `if (yes == '1')` とすべきではないかと。

Comment: @metropolis あぁ、あなたが正しいと思います。ありがとうございます。

Comment: お二人のどちらでもよいかと思いますが、もし完全な回答ができるのであれば、コメントではなく回答として投稿してみてはいかがでしょうか？
(誰でも自由に回答して良いとも思いますが一応)

Comment: 僭越ながらコメントを元にコミュニティwikiとして回答させていただきました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ご質問へのコメントを参考に、下記を見直してみてください。

- `class`の型を宣言する時は`new`を使わない

  - `new`は`Kama kama = new Kama();`のように[インスタンス](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9)作成時に使用します
- スペル修正

  - `IOExcepion` → `IOException`
  - `ptintln` → `println`
- `if`の中で代入演算子(`=`)ではなく比較演算子(`==`)を使う
- `System.in.read()`は入力された**文字コード**を返すので`char型`と比較する

修正後のコード例:

```
public class Kama {

    static String name = "ああああ様";
    static int yen;
    static int seki;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        int yes = System.in.read();

        if (yes == '1') {
        //if (yes == 49) { // '1'は文字コードの49(0x31)と同値
            System.out.println("ありがとう!!" + name);
        } else {
            System.out.println("キャンセルされました。" + name);
        }
        System.out.println("yes is" + yes);
    }
}
```